# Get the values from the database in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-edittext

I saved the EditText value in SQLite database and I want the to view all values from the database in ListView or TextView.

How it can be done?

Please help me.

Comment: Let's have a look at **[this](http://coenraets.org/blog/2010/09/tutorial-building-an-android-application-in-6-steps/)** tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

The Notepad tutorial shows you how to pull information out of a database using a `Cursor` then how to display it in a `ListView` using the `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

It can be found here: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html